# Drawing thin line before points changes size of points

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I draw a "very thin" line with `\tkzDrawLine` and then some points with
`\tkzDrawPoints`, the size parameter is ignored.  I suppose it's a bug?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=8](o,a)
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=8](o,a)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mixing `tkz` keys with `tikz` keys. The style `very thin` sets `\pgflinewidth` and `tkz-euclide` defines `size` in terms of `\pgflinewidth`.

Since `very thin` sets `\pgflinewidth` to 0.2pt, from the initial value of 0.4pt, in the second picture you get that the factor 8 produces a circle *half* as wide as in the first picture.

Possible workarounds:

1. Draw all lines and then say `\tikzset{thin}` to restore the value of `\pgflinewidth`
2. Remember to double the factors
3. Define a new style, `abssize` that uses the default value of 0.4pt

In the following test file the workarounds are implemented.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\pgfkeys{
  /drawpoint/.cd, 
  abssize/.code = {
    \tikzset{
      point style/.append style={
        minimum size = #1*0.4pt
      }
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=8](o,a)
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
  \tikzset{thin}
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=8](o,a)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=16](o,a)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,1/0/a,-1/0/b}
  \tkzDrawLine[very thin](a,b)
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, abssize=8](o,a)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]